# Prevent to remove cart items for disable product

Tags: magento2

I have placed an order successfully from the storefront.
Now I have disabled those order item from admin.
then those order quote item is empty.

Question: I want to prevent to remove cart items for the disabled product.
Please advise.

Comment: please share screenshots

Comment: Which type of screenshot do you need?

Comment: u have to process steps

Comment: For that, you need to add custom code. Because default Magento doesn't provide this feature.